# Changing Value of Combo Box to another Value in VB

Tags: string, vb.net, combobox, data-manipulation

I am trying to change the value of a combo box value "Black Shredded - 7.90" to just show "Black Shredded" when it is selected

```
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim strString1 As String
    Dim strString2 As String

    strString1 = cboProduct.SelectedItem
    intIndex = strString1.IndexOf(" ")
    strString2 = strString1.Remove(intIndex + 9)

    If cboProduct.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        cboProduct.Text = strString2
    End If
```

I went through the values and they show as they should but it isn't changing the combobox value what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just added `Strings` to the `ComboBox` in the first place then you need to replace the existing item with the new value. This:

```vb
cboProduct.Text = strString2
```

should be this:

```vb
cboProduct.Items(cboProduct.SelectedIndex) = strString2
```

You can just use `0` rather than `cboProduct.SelectedIndex`, given that you have already confirmed that that is the index at that point.

Setting the `Text` property doesn't affect the items at all. If `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDown` then the specified text will be displayed but no item will be selected. If `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDownList` then the item with that text will be selected, if one exists. Either way, no item is added or changed.